"Every Cat loves its mother or father"

"Every Cat loves its mother or father"
$\forall x ( \operatorname {Cat}(x) \land (\operatorname {Loves}(x,\operatorname{Mother}) \lor \operatorname {Loves}(x,\operatorname {Father}) )$

Although I know that a universal quantifier cannot be used with conjunction (not because of syntax error), I have issues understanding why the above translation is incorrect. I mean, it does sound correct:

for every x that is a cat and ( it loves its mother or it loves its father ).


Part (3) doesn't mean "for every x that is a cat and (it loves its mother or it loves its father)" (which is not even syntactically correct because of the "and" having no lefthandside argument). What it means is "every x is a cat and loves its mother or loves its father". It is incorrect because some $x$s are not cats.
What you may have meant to write

for every x that is a cat, ( it loves its mother or it loves its father ),

that is,

Every Cat loves its mother or father,

is actually symbolised as

$\forall x ( \operatorname {Cat}(x)\implies (\operatorname {Loves}(x,\operatorname {Mother}) \lor \operatorname {Loves}(x,\operatorname{Father}) )$.


Addendum following the OP's subsequent comments
It will be elucidating for you to ponder the difference between these two statements:

$\forall x \,( \operatorname {Cat}(x)\land \operatorname {Carnivore}(x) )$
$\forall x \,( \operatorname {Cat}(x)\Rightarrow \operatorname {Carnivore}(x) )$


 Everything is a carnivorous cat versus Every cat is carnivorous.


You mean the LHS of $\land$ doesn't have a choice? But even for all the things that are not cats this whole statement would be false? So what's the problem? I don't get it.
I mean let's say x is a bike, so cat(x) is false because x is not a cat, and the RHS of $\land$ can be anything. I am sure I am misunderstanding how predicate function works but I am not sure how.

@diskhank What I meant is that in "for every x that is a cat and blah", there is no "LHS of $\land$"; another "blah" is missing in front of "and" for the sentence to be synctactically correct. If what you intended to write was "for every x, x is a cat and blah" then it would be synctactically correct, and false indeed whatever "blah" is.

I still don't get it to be honest, I know why the implication one is correct (that you have mentioned) , but let's say the $x$ is a person then $cat(x)$ is false so it RHS of $\land$ can be anything as the LHS of it is false (i.e. a person may love either of the parents or none at all), which is correct.
$x$ can be a bike and $cat(x)$ is again false so we don't care about what on the right of $\land$.
$x$ can be a cat and we get our desired result. So what's the problem because $∀x.¬Cat(x) ∨ Loves(x, mother(x)) ∨ Loves(x, father(x))$, this is correct answer so why not the one I mentioned

(Answer to your comment before you edited it) I agree with all this (as explicited in the second part of my comment). The problem I was pointing is that "(for every x that is a cat) and blah" means nothing (as explained in the first part).

So it is solely wrong because cat(x) is asserting x must be a cat and we can encounter any x that is not a cat, that makes it invalid?

@dikshank We are discussing 3 distinct subjects and we agree on at least the first one: 1) $\forall x$  ( Cat(x) $\land$ (Loves(x,Mother) $\lor$ Loves(x,Father) ) is indeed "solely wrong because" $(\exists x)\ \neg$Cat$(x)$. 2) $\forall x$  ( Cat(x) $\land$ (Loves(x,Mother) $\lor$ Loves(x,Father) ) is not the correct formalization of "Every Cat loves its mother or father" (which might be true or false: we don't know much about cats' feelings) 3) "(for every x that is a cat) and (it loves its mother or it loves its father)" is neither true nor false: it is just meaningless.

@AnneBauval That gives different perspective I think I get it now.

@ryang Thank you for the addendum; that was really helpful in clearing my head.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
